# Test SharePoint Addin locally (Without deploying to server)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, aspx

I am creating a SharePoint Addin but I want to be able to view the changes immediately (like with HTML). Currently, it deploys the addin to the SharePoint Website (hosted on O365) every time it runs, this takes 1-3 minutes each time. This is quite annoying when testing small things. Is there a way that I can open the .aspx file and show the result (like how we can open the .html file and see the changes made).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your pain. Its very annoying and frustrating some times when you make a small mistake and need to deploy the complete addin and wait while its deploying.

But there is a tool available in VS Market place named as `SPFastDeploy`. You can use to deploy a single asset file instead of deploying the complete app. Follow the URL to know more about it. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCurranMVP.SPFastDeploy

Comment: I hope this will solves your problem.